# How to run a TensorFlow in parallel with some other processing on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python, parallel-processing, raspberry-pi3, parallelism-amdahl

I would like to run a continuous stream with the PiCamera on the Raspberry Pi 3 and also do other computations in parallel with this stream.

I only have to take from that stream(process) the object that it detected. I will post here the code I have so far. It doesn't enter in the **`computation()`** function. It just starts the camera and detects the objects there and stays in that process.

I've tried using **`multiprocessing`** module from Python but it doesn't seem to work.

```py
def startRecord():
    frame_rate_calc = 1
    freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT)
    camera.framerate = 10
    camera.vflip = True
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
        object_detected = "none"
        t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
        frame = np.copy(frame1.array)
        frame.setflags(write=1)
        frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

        # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

        # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visualize the results')
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8,
            min_score_thresh=0.40)

        if classes[0][0] == 1 and scores[0][0] > 0.98:
            object_detected = "circle"
        elif classes[0][0] == 2 and scores[0][0] > 0.98:
            object_detected = "donnut"
        elif classes[0][0] == 3 and scores[0][0] > 0.98:
            object_detected = "square"
        elif classes[0][0] == 4 and scores[0][0] > 0.98:
            object_detected = "alphabot"

        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc), (30, 50), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
        cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

        t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
        time1 = (t2 - t1) / freq
        frame_rate_calc = 1 / time1

        # Press 'q' to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

        rawCapture.truncate(0)
    camera.close()


def computation():
    print("OUTSIDE OF CAPTURE")
    print(object_detected)
### Picamera ###
if camera_type == 'picamera':
    # Initialize Picamera and grab reference to the raw capture
    p1 = Process(target=startRecord())
    p2 = Process(target=computation())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is clear, yet your posted code will need some polishing and RPi3 will be the hardest part of the journey:

- The **`multiprocessing`** module is indeed capable of spawning a pool of sub-processes, yet at an immense cost - both in **`[PSPACE]`** it populates a FULL-COPY of the python interpreter session ( statefully and that grabs immense amounts of RAM for each replicated copy ) and in `[PTIME]`, as it takes the more time the more sub-processes one spawns ( a one-time cost, yet very important for overhead-strict [Amdahl's Law re-formulated maximum parallel speedup-benefit evaluations](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallelism-amdahl/info) )
- There is not more than 1 MB RAM on RPi3 IIRC, so either your TF-model has to be indeed miniature, or you have to carefully spawn the TF-dedicated sub-process in a way it does not replicate the same TF-BLOBs in the main-session ( and not leaving the same BLOB there ) - quite a tricky part.
- Still, you need a coordination between both ends of your intended distributed processing. One process cannot put its hand into a pocket of another process and take any value outside of the neighbour's explicit will ( and control ). At the moment: -- one side, invoked as the **`p1 = Process( target = startRecord() )`** never calls a **`computation()`** to be ever done -- the other side, invoked as the **`p2 = Process( target = computation() )`** never ever receives ( and by its design it even does not require to be done so ) a single piece of data from anywhere else ( the only reference to some variable/object - the **`object_detected`** - was already pre-copied from the main session, in such a state ( if there was any such present at all ) it had during the sub-process instantiation, and has become a fully-separated replica ( intentionally un-connected and un-coordinated w.r.t. any, now "external", changes - as this very set of features liberates the sub-process of any central main-session's GIL-lock coordination overheads and the sub-processes may work independently, enjoying increased levels of `[CONCURRENT]` process-execution(s) )

### Solution:

a) verify, if sizing meets the realms of RPi3 RAM constraints

b) right-size the main-session before spawning any specialised sub-processes

c) design inter-process communications ( default Queue/deQueue may become un-fit for fast and efficient processing - may enjoy a smarter and more controllable signalling/messaging framework alike the ZeroMQ `ipc://` for moving raw byte-blocks in an almost Zero-Copy manner - yes, here again and again, RPi3 RAM-ceiling will hurt you both `[PSPACE]`-wise ( so as to fit inside on both en-Queue / de-Queue sides overhead ) and also `[PTIME]`-wise ( as the add-on latencies will grow, might be beyond one's process-control acceptable thresholds ) )